# Can I get a visual indicator when I drop a mark?

Tags: mark

I like using marks, but I wouldn't mind having a visual indicator of some sort that maybe shows me "you've dropped mark x here", perhaps a letter in the gutter or some sort of line or character highlighting.

Is there a plugin or something for that that works well? I didn't come up with anything on search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a plugin or something for that that works well?

Why yes there is! I use [kshenoy/vim-signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature), and highly recommend it.

From the README:

> vim-signature is a plugin to place, toggle and display marks.
>
> Apart from the above, you can also
>
> - Navigate forward/backward by position/alphabetical order
> - Displaying multiple marks (upto 2, limited by the signs feature)
> - Placing custom signs `!@#$%^&*()` as visual markers

And here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Although I don't typically use the more advanced features, I just use it for the visual display of marks.